# Al realizar git pull resulta en fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: git, git-push, gitlab

Estuve realizando `git clone https://bashir.ejemplo.ws/UTP.git` , 
luego un pull con el comando 
`git pull origin develop` y aparecio este error:

```
* branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD  
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

¿Alguna vez les ha pasado? quisiera bajar mis fuentes pero nose que hacer exactamente, he visto que  usan un

> git fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba corriendo este comando, usar `develop` o `master` de acuerdo a la rama con el inconveniente.

`git pull origin develop --allow-unrelated-histories`

[Documentacion](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories)

Comment: Utilice el comando y me sale este mensaje:
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
*** Please tell me who you are.
Run
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'marvin@marvin-VirtualBox.(none)')

Comment: no has indicado tu nombre de usuario y correo en la configuracion global de git?

Comment: Si es asi debes correr los comandos `git config --global user.email "tucorreo@dominio.com"` y git config --global user.name "Tu nombre usado en github"